# Subtracting date in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my form:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='6FPkks049G8IWRkLW6mptEKGRwVevsVo' />
    <label for="id_date">Date:</label></th><td><input class="vDateField" id="id_date" name="date" size="10" type="text" />

    <label for="id_rday">How many days before?</label></th><td>
    <select id="id_rday" name="rday">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7" selected="selected">7</option>
    </select>

    <label for="id_remind_at">Reminder date:</label></th><td><input id="id_remind_at" name="remind_at" type="text" />

    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

How to create something like this:

If user choose `id_date` and `id_rdate`, field `id_reminder` will be automatically filled:

```
`id_reminder` = `id_day - id_rday`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the day of the month from the `Date` object, then subtract:

```
var today = new Date();
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 5);  // 5 days ago
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp